Gaussian Distribution vs Gaussian Noise?
I am trying to understand Donsker's Theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donsker%27s_theorem):

Let $F_n$ be the \textit{empirical distribution function} of the
sequence of i.i.d. random variables $X_1, X_2, X_3, \ldots$ with
distribution function $F$. Define the centered and scaled version of
$F_n$ by
$$ G_n(x) = \sqrt{n} ( F_n(x) - F(x) ) $$
indexed by $x \in \mathbb{R}$. By the classical central limit theorem,
for fixed $x$, the random variable $G_n(x)$ converges in distribution
to a Gaussian (normal) random variable $G(x)$ with zero mean and
variance $F(x)(1 - F(x))$ as the sample size $n$ grows.
Theorem: The sequence of $G_n(x)$, as random elements of the Skorokhod
space $\mathcal{D}(-\infty,\infty)$, converges in distribution to a
Gaussian process $G$ with zero mean and covariance given by
$$ \operatorname{cov}[G(s), G(t)] = \mathbb{E}[G(s) G(t)] =
> \min\{F(s), F(t)\} - F(s)F(t). $$
The process $G(x)$ can be written as $B(F(x))$ where $B$ is a standard
Brownian bridge on the unit interval.

Here is my confusion:

We start the theorem by assuming that $x_1, x_2, x_3...$ are i.i.d. At this point, there is no Stochastic Process
We define a new variable $G_n(x)$. Using CLT, we say that $G_n$ is normally distributed (i.e. Gaussian Random Variable).
Since $G_n$ is a function of $x$, this means that $G_n$ is still not a Stochastic Process.
However, now we say that $G_n$ converges to a function $G(x)$. $G(x)$ is a Gaussian Process, i.e. a Stochastic Process

But if we look at the definition of a Gaussian Process (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_process), we see that the mean and variance of the Gaussian Process are functions of time, and are actually a Stochastic Process.
This is my question: Originally, it seemed like that index $n$ in the original $X_n$ were mostly arbitrary - we could have written $x_3$ before $x_1$ and it would have no meaningful implication. However, by the time we get to $G(x)$, there is a now a meaningful ordering in the indices - if $x_3$ is written before $x_1$ then suddenly the mean and variance are different. The original $x$ are time independent but the function $G$ is time dependent.
How can a Non-Stochastic Process be transformed into a Stochastic Process?
